# Writing a generic method for sorting a set of comparables of any type

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have something like this:

```
public class A implements Comparable<A> {
  ...
  @Override
  public int compareTo(A obj) {
     ...
  }
}

public class B implements Comparable<B> {
  ...
  @Override
  public int compareTo(B obj) {
     ...
  }
}
```

I also have a bunch of HashSet collections that are slowly populated over the course of a program, e.g.:

```
private Collection<A> col = new HashSet<A>();
```

At the very end of the program I would like to convert them to sorted lists so they can be displayed sorted:

```
public class Utils {
  public static <T> Collection<Comparable<T>> toSortedList(Collection<Comparable<T>> col) {
    List<Comparable<T>> sorted = new ArrayList<Comparable<T>>(col);
    Collections.sort(sorted);
    return sorted;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I get the compile error:

```
The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<Comparable<T>>)
```

How do I go about modifying the above so HashSets of both Comparable<A> and Comparable<B> can be passed to this method? Thanks!

Comment: Look at the declaration of that `sort` method and copy its use of a generic parameter. Replace your `Comparable<T>` with `T` everywhere.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis If I use T instead of Comparable<T> then the compiler complains "The method sort(List<T extends Comparable<? super T>>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<T>)"

Comment: `public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Collection<T> toSortedList(Collection<T>)` is the correct signature.  Look at the full signature of `Collections.sort`.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman Thanks that works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` generic syntax:

```
public class Utils {
    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Collection<T> toSortedList(Collection<T> col) {
        List<T> sorted = new ArrayList<T>(col);
        Collections.sort(sorted);
        return sorted;
    }
}
```